# Why can't we solve the Brachistochrone Problem like this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

I'm starting to read about Calculus of Variations and one of the first problem the text tackled using this tool was [the Brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve), which was given by the functional 
$$F[y(x)]=\int_a^b \frac{ds}{v}$$
with $ds=\sqrt{1+[y'(x)]^2}dx$ and $v=y'(x)$.

The author then solves the problem by invoking the equality of potential and kinetic energy, but do we need to do this? Just looking at the integrand $f$, we see that 
$$f=\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}$$
with $u=y'(x)$. Using the Beltrami identity, we obtain
$$C=\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}+\frac{1}{u^2\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}}=\frac{u^2+2}{u^2\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}}$$
**Can't we just solve this as an ordinary equation and then integrate to obtain $y(x)$?**
*This is clearly wrong, since the solutions to the equation above are constants, so $y(x)$ becomes linear in $x$, which is not the solution to the Brachistochrone problem, but wherein lies the mistake?*

Comment: When you write the denominator $y'=\sqrt{y'^2}$ you assume that $y'>0$. Why? By the way, constants from Beltrami identity may be not extremals, it is not equivalent to Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: @A.G. Huh, is it as simple as that? In general, can't we solve the problem when $f=\frac{\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}}{u}$, without invoking the physical considerations?

Comment: @A.G. What do you mean by "extremals" in this case?

Comment: No need for physical considerations, one can apply Beltrami to the origianal $\frac{\sqrt{1+u^2}}{u}$ directly.

Comment: Extremals are solutions to Euler-Lagrange equation. Solutions to Beltrami identity are those and constant functions. This is because Beltrami identity is obtained after multiplying both sides of E-L by $y'$. It may add false solutions $y'=0$ (constant functions).

Comment: @A.G. Ah, that's a pretty critical point (no pun intended!), thanks!

Comment: @A.G. With $y(0)=0$ I get $y(x)=\pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{\frac{C^2+\sqrt{C^2+8}C \pm 4}{1-C^2}}$. How is this compatible with a cycloid (the known solution)? If you would write up an answer including your first remark as well as how you would solve it using the Beltrami identity (and without invoking the physics), I'd accept it in a heart-beat!

Comment: Now I see the trouble. You write the denominator as $v=y'$, but the speed $v$ is not the derivative of the trajectory wrt $x$, it is derivative wrt time! To express it in terms of $y(x)$ one applies the energy conservation law (see, for example, [here](http://www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/math/variationalCalculus/variationalCalculus.pdf))

Comment: @A.G. Great, thank you so much, it all makes sense now (there's a mistake in the notes I was reading, it explicitly says "$v(x)=y'(x)$")! I could only get linear solutions to the other mess (even if I used the E-L equation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *A.G.* didn't want to post an answer, I'll do it, just do get the question off the unanswered list - but all credit should go to *A.G.*.

First of all, one can't write $$\frac{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}{u}=\sqrt{u^{-2}+1}$$ since $u$ could be negative.

And second of all, there was a mistake in the problem formulation:
$$v(x)=y'(t) \not=y'(x)$$
so the substitution using conservation of energy was necessary to get a $v(x)$ expressed as a function of $y(x)$.